# My CrawlSpider in Scrapy does not follow the rules

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I'm having troubles making my spider work in Scrapy v1.0.5:

```
class MaddynessSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "maddyness"
allowed_domains = ["www.maddyness.com"]

start_urls = [
    'http://www.maddyness.com/finance/levee-de-fonds/'
]

_extract_article_links = Rule(
    LinkExtractor(
        allow=(
            r'http://www\.maddyness\.com/finance/levee-de-fonds/'
        ),
        restrict_xpaths=('//article[starts-with(@class,"post")]'),
    ),
    callback='parse_article',
)

_extract_pagination_links = Rule(
    LinkExtractor(
        allow=(
            r'http://www\.maddyness\.com/finance/levee-de-fonds/',
            r'http://www\.maddyness\.com/page/'
        ),
        restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="pagination-wrapper"]'),
    )
)

rules = (
    _extract_article_links,
    _extract_pagination_links,
)

def _extract_date(self, url):
    match = re.match(r'\S+/\S+/\S+/(\S+/\S+/\S+)/\S+/', url)
    return match.group(1) if match else None

def _extract_slug(self, url):
    match = re.match(r'\S+/\S+/\S+/\S+/\S+/\S+/(\S+)/', url)
    return match.group(1) if match else None

"""
Parsing function after each page is scraped
"""
def parse_article(self, response):
    print("la")
    article = NewsItem()
    loader = BeautifulSoupItemLoader(item=article, response=response, from_encoding='cp1252')

    #loader.add_xpath('company_name', u'//meta[@property="article:tag"]/@content')

    return loader.load_item()
```

I never reach my callback function parse_article and the output shows me this :

```
[Anaconda2] C:\dev\hubble\workspaces\python\batch\scripts\Crawler>scrapy crawl maddyness

2016-04-28 17:00:03 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.5 started (bot: Crawler)
2016-04-28 17:00:03 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto
2016-04-28 17:00:03 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'Crawler.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['Crawler.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'Crawler'}
2016-04-28 17:00:04 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2016-04-28 17:00:04 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2016-04-28 17:00:04 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2016-04-28 17:00:04 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: ElasticsearchPipeline

2016-04-28 17:00:04 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-04-28 17:00:04 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-04-28 17:00:04 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-04-28 17:00:04 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.maddyness.com/finance/levee-de-fonds/> from <GET http://www.maddyness.com/finance/levee-de-fonds/>
2016-04-28 17:00:04 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.maddyness.com/index.php?s=%23MaddyPitch> from <GET http://www.maddyness.com/index.php?s=%23MaddyPitch>
2016-04-28 17:00:04 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.maddyness.com/index.php?s=%23MaddyPitch> (referer: None)
2016-04-28 17:00:04 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.maddyness.com/finance/levee-de-fonds/> (referer: None)
2016-04-28 17:00:05 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)Spider closed
2016-04-28 17:00:05 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:    {    
'downloader/request_bytes': 1080,
 'downloader/request_count': 4,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 4,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 48223,
 'downloader/response_count': 4,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 28, 15, 0, 5, 123000),
'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
'log_count/INFO': 7,
'response_received_count': 2,
'scheduler/dequeued': 4,
'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 4,
'scheduler/enqueued': 4,
'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4,
'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 28, 15, 0, 4, 590000)}
2016-04-28 17:00:05 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help, I'm totally stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just that you are *redirected to the "https" from "http"* and all of the subsequent article links now start with `https` while your rules are configured to extract `http` links only. Fix that:

```
_extract_article_links = Rule(
    LinkExtractor(
        allow=(
            r'https?://www\.maddyness\.com/finance/levee-de-fonds/'
        ),
        restrict_xpaths=('//article[starts-with(@class,"post")]'),
    ),
    callback='parse_article',
)

_extract_pagination_links = Rule(
    LinkExtractor(
        allow=(
            r'https?://www\.maddyness\.com/finance/levee-de-fonds/',
            r'https?://www\.maddyness\.com/page/'
        ),
        restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="pagination-wrapper"]'),
    )
)
```

`s?` here would match `s` 0 or 1 time making it work for both `http` and `https`.

Comment: Indeed !! Thanks very much !